# Connection Time Out: Private_Pub + SSL + Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, nginx, private-pub

I have implemented Private_Pub with SSL and I am running that over port 4443 as recommended in: https://github.com/ryanb/private_pub#serving-faye-over-https-with-thin

However, whenever I actually use the private_pub service I receive the following error:

Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Connection timed out - connect(2) for "www.mysite.com" port 4443

The really odd thing is that it was working on another server before we migrated providers.

I have ensured port 4443 is open by telnet-ing to it successfully. I have played around with the nginx config without any luck. I have restarted the thin server several times just to see if I get lucky.

I am able to access: https://www.mysite.com:4443/faye/faye.js

Can anybody point me in the right direction here?

Edit: Added my nginx config file:

```
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx.log  debug;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
passenger_root /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/passenger-4.0.52;
passenger_ruby /home/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/wrappers/ruby;
passenger_app_env production;

include       mime.types;

default_type  application/octet-stream;
sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
         listen       80;
         root /var/www/mysite/current/public;
         rails_env production;
         passenger_enabled on;
}


server {
    listen 443;
    root /var/www/mysite/current/public;
    rails_env production;
    proxy_read_timeout 1200;
    client_max_body_size 20m;

    error_log  /var/log/nginx.log  debug;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /var/server.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/server.key;

    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto: https;
    passenger_pass_header X-Forwarded-Proto;
    passenger_enabled on;

    # Tried it also without this part to no avail
    location /faye {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    root /var/applications/current/faye;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4443;
    break;
}

}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen 443;

    server_name www.mysite.co mysite.co;

    return 302 $scheme://www.mysite.com$request_uri;
}

}
```

Comment: please add your nginx config file..

Comment: Thanks. Added my nginx config.